# Can .NET Core 3.0 Web Api and Angular 10 applications hosted on same AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance?

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core-webapi

I have hosted .Net core web API 3.0 in AWS EC2 on ports 5000 & 5001 (https://localhost:5001 & http://localhost:5000)
I have also hosted angular(10)(on port 4200-default) app on the same AWS EC2 Instance and tried to access the api end points.
In security group I have allowed all trafic- all port any where, allowed 5000,50001,4200.

In browser while I am trying to access the page I am getting error as net:ERROR CONNECTION REFUSED.

while trying in local Its working fine!!

Comment: Do you perhaps have [CORS issues](https://blog.container-solutions.com/a-guide-to-solving-those-mystifying-cors-issues)?

Comment: I have allowed CORS in web API. and also I am able to access while I hosted applications on windows 10                                         
 services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    });
            });